# Moving/backing up xcom save files

Tags: steam, xcom-ufo-defense

I'm hoping to move a full set of XCom (the original) save games from a steam install on one computer to a steam install on a second.

I've seen the UFOpaedia entry on save games but can't seem to get heads or tails out of if I can just copy what straight across. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bonus points: can I use dropbox to keep the save games linked all cloud like between the machines?

Comment: I see no harm in just trying to copy them and seeing if they can get loaded from the other computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each saved game in XCOM is put into a folder inside the game directory, GAME_1, GAME_2, ... up to GAME_10.  You can just copy/move the folder to your new computer where xcom is installed.

As for using dropbox, the entire XCOM game is so small that you can probably just have steam install it straight into your dropbox folder*, see this link for details: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7710-tdlc-0426

*This is assuming your steam library is small enough to fit into dropbox, other wise, ignore this suggestion.  Either way, you can use it to transfer saves with no problem.